# Recommendations on apache tuning for chat application

Tags: chat, xmpp, apache

I have a chat application (xmpp / muc) that is going to be served by apache (we might change to nginx later but right now it's not easily done). If a user is in 2 rooms, he'll have between 2 and 4 active connections to the server (long-polling connections), so if we have 200 users per room and we have 5 rooms, what should the ServerLimit, MaxClients be set to? For example, these are the default values:

ServerLimit      256

MaxClients       256

MaxRequestsPerChild  4000

Thanks,

Comment: You may take a look into the mpm_event_module. It is experimental in apache 2.2, but it may definitely help you. I'm not sure if it supports ssl.

Answer (score 0):

Each user should only have a single connection to the XMPP server if your using something like BOSH to make the Web->XMPP connection.  Each MUC room activity will be sent to the XMPP server with the user's JID as the target and that will cause the server to send that to the appropriate BOSH connection.  Same for presence.

The information you need to load balance the Apache setup is the same as load balancing any long-polling connection - XMPP doesn't add anything exotic to the mix.  An XMPP BOSH connection is a long-polling connection to your web server which is then sent to a persistent connection to the XMPP server - causing 2 sockets to be opened per user connect.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing this a pre-fork Apache....

If you've got 1000 concurrent chat connections, then you need at least 1000 webservers (presumably you'll be serving up static content too, and you say that each presence results in 2 connections - so you can double the 1000) - a ServerLimit/MaxClients of 256 is not going to cut it, you probably need around 2200 to support this (but without hard metrics its hard to give an exact figure).

This is a ridiculously large amount. To support this I'd be looking for 3 boxes, each with about 2Gb free memory before the webserver is started.

MaxRequestsPerChild is not really relevant other than the fact you want some turnover of processes, particularly if you are using long polling.

This is one of the reasons why COMET is not a good idea. Using AJAX polling would be much more efficient. Assuming this is not something you can change, you might want to have a look at using a threaded Apache webserver which is marginally more memory efficient,

C.

Comment: I'm sorry, just because Apache can't handle Comet efficiently, doesn't make it a bad idea. It also doesn't make AJAX Polling more desirable since it will produce A LOT more database load. It's by far more efficient to have 1000 clients longpolling for 2 minutes than having to handle 1000 requests every second (if you want real time). also if you calculate that they only come every 5 seconds, you'll still have 200 RPS for NOTHING! This gives you horrible DB Load for literally nothing!

Comment: Just because it won't work doesn't make it a bad idea? Really? Wwill produce A LOT more database load" No - what kind of person tries relay chat via a database?